# logstash zabbix metric without tags in log

Tags: logstash, metrics, zabbix

We have the following setup.

- 1 central logstash server (behind that we have an elasticsearch
  cluster based on two nodes)
- 1 central zabbix server
- 10 Servers with logstash-forwarder

On our logstash server we are getting syslogs apache/nginx access and error logs from 10 mentioned servers trough logstash-forwarder.

Since we want to see the amount of error logs per server per minute in a nice graph in our zabbix system we are using the metrics plugin (http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/contrib-plugins)

Here is the PROBLEM:
we are currently not able the get the logs with the correct tags from the plugin to send them to zabbix.

logstash-forwarder confing and logstash server conf see link
https://db.tt/4cn8DWi2

if anyone has an idea, how we can get rid of this problem, we would be very thankful.

Comment: Please specifiy your problem: are you getting no messages at all or do they have the wrong tags?

Comment: Also do not rely on the deprecated 'tags' element. Use conditional outputs as described by the [config language](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are messing up top level sections in your config files, [check the logstash config language](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration).

Each file should be something like this;

```
# section input
input {
    # multiple plugin defintions *within* the input section
    file {}
    file {}
}

# section filter
filter {
    grok{}
    grok{}
    grok{}
}

# section output
output {
    elasticsearch{}
    stoud{}
}
```

Your config looks like this:

```
input {
    file {}
}

input {
    file {}
}

output {
    elasticsearch{}
}

output {
    stoud{}
}
```